# Stuck at Lenovo screen when shutting down laptop

Tags: 22.04, shutdown

I installed ubuntu on my windows machine and it has both OS now. The grub works fine when starting up and I can choose between windows and ubuntu. I also have switched off secure boot from bios screen as switching it on will end up with the grub not showing up.

My issue is that when I power down Ubuntu it gets stuck at the Lenovo screen. With windows there is no issues. And starting up is fine as I said before.

In case it’s some graphics issue, the machine has both intel iris xe and Nvidia RTX A2000

Any ideas on how I may go about fixing this?